# paypal express oscommerce only sending name and email when buyer orders an item from store

Tags: php, oscommerce

The php script oscommerce uses for paypal express , and other paypal modules only sends the buyers name and email when they order something. I found a quick fix for a different paypal module that sends all the useful information when some one buys something ,i.e. address what items they bought and quantity.

i found this fix on the web [here](http://www.membuy.com/tips-and-tricks/5-how-to-show-the-item-name-when-i-submit-the-paypal-checkout-info-at-your-free-oscommerce-templates.html), but it is for a different paypal module is there a fix for paypal express? This will be extremely helpful for me, thank you

if needed i can send the php script for paypal express , its over 400 lines. I added the code to [paste bin here](http://pastebin.com/epkwb61F)

is there a fix for paypal express on the web some where or can some one help me to get paypal express to work thank you

Comment: Have you tried the fix on this module? Try it and see if it works

Comment: I did , the text they tell you to search for isn't in the php code for the paypal express module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to add some parameters into the post request. In your pastebin file (which is not the latest version of the module) it is about lines 197-201.

You can find  the list of parameters here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing under "Integrating Order Details into the Express Checkout Flow" section.

If you have at least basic PHP knowledge it will not be a problem for you to do this. If something is still not clear please ask.

Comment: will try this , need to learn basic php first but atleast i will get it done if i get it ill +50 you thanks

Comment: also the verison i'm using is the latest supported by my friends server